# Setting velocity properties

Tags: maven-2, maven, velocity

I have occurence building a maven archetype where I want to do something like this

```
#set( $controllerPackage = ${package}\.${artifactId})
```

i.e. set the controllerPackage variable to equal the result of string concatentaion of the following three elements ($package,'.',$artifactId)

However this is obvioulsy not correct syntax - I get this

> Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 4, column 40.  Encountered: "." (46), after : "\"

Is there a way I can include a period in my outputted string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a string, use quotes.

```
#set( $controllerPackage = "${package}.${artifactId}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` for string concatenation:

```
#set( $controllerPackage = ${package} + "." + ${artifactId})
```

Comment: I could not get this to work inside the archetype - I have solved the problem which meant i needed to use the properties separate largely as above